# Debugging station rating — it is 53% when it should be around 82% — what's missing?

Tags: openttd

I followed the [OpenTTD Wiki](https://wiki.openttd.org/en/Manual/Game%20Mechanics/), which explains how ratings are calculated, and also cross-checked with the [implementation](https://github.com/OpenTTD/OpenTTD/blob/master/src/station_cmd.cpp#L3611C19-L3611C19). According to this table, I should get around 210 points, which should map roughly to 82%.

[image: table]

- I'm in 1961 and use trains with 144 max speed
- Vehicles are older than 2 years
- Two trains are always at the station loading goods
- No cargo waiting
- Built a statue in this town

I have a similar setup for other industries, and their ratings roughly match the wiki.

In this case, I'm transporting goods, and the target town stopped accepting them. I'm getting only transfer fees as a result. Does it mean that despite the fact that cargo was transported away from this station, since it hasn't been delivered, it is still accounted towards this station?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it looks like transferred goods are still counted towards the original station. When I entered "units of cargo waiting" from another station (which is storying them after a town stopped accepting goods), I got exactly the rating that I'm given in a game:

[image]

And when I rerouted goods to another city and cleared the transferred goods, I got the expected 82%.